# Nuget private source - possible to set condition in PackageReference?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I'm setting up a private nuget source via github. All is working well, using a `nuget.config` like this (credentials section redacted):

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<my-company>/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>...</packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Note, I'm not clearing other packageSources: I still need to use the public nuget source. I'm just adding an additional private source in addition.

As I said, all is working, and I can add packages just fine from either source. But I got to worrying when I checked the `PackageReference` entries in the `csproj`. It doesn't indicate which source to use for the package.

For example, in this instance, `MyCompany.Common` is coming from my private source, and `Newtonsoft.Json` is coming from the public nuget source.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MyCompany.Common" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

But what if there is a public package with the same name? I tried this, and scarily it works.
So in other words, if someone guesses my private package name, the next time someone clones the repo and builds, it's quite likely Visual Studio will fetch the package from the wrong source.

Is there a way to prevent this? I've been reading the [Nuget PackageReference docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#adding-a-packagereference-condition) and the only thing that seems even remotely close might be a `Condition`:

```
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452'" />
```

But it looks like this is more to set conditions based on solution/project/system configuration, not package source.

Is there a conditional that can specify the package source? Or is there something else that can specify the nuget source for a particular package?

I think this might be related to [this article](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/02/10/researcher-breaches-systems-of-over-35-companies/?utm_source=feedly&utm_medium=webfeeds).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an interesting post here

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/3-ways-to-mitigate-risk-using-private-package-feeds/

I found the most practical way is to go with the lock mode, with which you will have a package.lock.json file like this

```
"dependencies": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0": {
      "Newtonsoft.Json": {
        "type": "Direct",
        "requested": "[12.0.1, )",
        "resolved": "12.0.1",
        "contentHash": "pBR3wCgYWZGiaZDYP+HHYnalVnPJlpP1q55qvVb+adrDHmFMDc1NAKio61xTwftK3Pw5h7TZJPJEEVMd6ty8rg=="
      }
    }
  }
```

The `contentHash` should secure the package.

The lock mode can be enabled by

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

In reading the link provided by @lastr2d2 in his answer, I found a paragraph that is also very apropos:

> For NuGet Gallery: An `ID prefix` can be registered by publishers to restrict uploads to the public gallery. Packages under a registered prefix can only be uploaded by approved accounts, which also protects against public substitution attacks. This reservation can be done **whether you intend to publish your packages to NuGet.org or not.** Using a registered ID prefix for private packages helps ensure that an attacker cannot claim any of your names."

(emphasis added)

I debated whether to add this as a comment under his answer, but ultimately decided that this is a full fledged solution in its own right, and thus should be a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft now offers Package Source Mapping starting with NuGet 6.0 and Visual Studio 2022: (excerpt)

Enabling Package Source Mapping

To opt into this feature, you must have a nuget.config file. Having a single nuget.config at the root of your repository is considered a best practice. See nuget.config documentation to learn more.

```
Declare your desired package sources in your nuget.config file.
Following your source declarations, add a <packageSourceMapping> element that specifies the desired mappings for each source.
Declare exactly one packageSource element for each source in use.
    Add as many patterns as you find necessary.

<!-- Define the package sources, nuget.org and contoso.com. -->
<!-- `clear` ensures no additional sources are inherited from another config file. -->
<packageSources>
  <clear />
  <!-- `key` can be any identifier for your source. -->
  <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  <add key="contoso.com" value="https://contoso.com/packages/" />
</packageSources>

<!-- Define mappings by adding package patterns beneath the target source. -->
<!-- Contoso.* packages and NuGet.Common will be restored from contoso.com, everything else from nuget.org. -->
<packageSourceMapping>
  <!-- key value for <packageSource> should match key values from <packageSources> element -->
  <packageSource key="nuget.org">
    <package pattern="*" />
  </packageSource>
  <packageSource key="contoso.com">
    <package pattern="Contoso.*" />
    <package pattern="NuGet.Common" />
  </packageSource>
</packageSourceMapping>
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-source-mapping#enabling-package-source-mapping

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no built-in functionality in NuGet to perform this sort of "source filtering", because that's outside its scope.

There are however numerous third-party (paid) NuGet server products that expose such a feature. Alternatively, you can write your own NuGet server that does this for you.